# Can't save the output of a function to a list or a string, How does a function return multiple values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, output

I created a function that returns grammatical characteristics to a set of words:

```
import nltk.tokenize
from io import StringIO

def get_pos_tag(string):
    detM =['un','le']
    nomM =['garçon','verre','chair']

    #Entréé
    test = nltk.word_tokenize(string)

    #Pos-Tag de chaque entréé
    for i in range(0,len(test)):

       #Déterminant masculin singulier
       if test[i] in detM:
           CAT = "Det"
           Nb = "Sg"
           GND = "M"
           return(test[i],":","CAT:",CAT,",","Genre:",GND,",","Nombre:",Nb)
      #Nom Masculin Singulier
      elif test[i] in nomM:
           CAT = "N"
           Nb = "Sg"
           GND = "M"
           return(test[i],":","CAT:",CAT,",","Genre:",GND,",","Nombre:",Nb)
```

Now in another script when I want to save the output of the function to either a string or a list, this is what am getting:

```
>>>import PosTag
>>> var1=PosTag.get_pos_tag("un garçon")
un : CAT: Det , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg
garçon : CAT: N , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg
>>> print (var1)
None
>>> var2=[]
>>> var2.append(PosTag.get_pos_tag("un garçon"))
un : CAT: Det , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg
garçon : CAT: N , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg
>>> print(var2)
[None]
```

And I need the result to be stored in a variable to use it next.

Comment: you have no return statement in your function. You are returning from somewhere else with the last line, or the indentation is broken. But if it is an indentation error, you would have an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it by return, but it only return one value, now I can't get both of the tags am only getting `un : CAT: Det , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg` the next one is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the [`yield`](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/) keyword. Yield essentially turns your function into a generator that will keep returning values until you reach the end.

```
def get_pos_tag(string):
    detM =['un','le']
    nomM =['garçon','verre','chair']

    #Entréé
    test = nltk.word_tokenize(string)

    #Pos-Tag de chaque entréé
    for i in range(0,len(test)):

       #Déterminant masculin singulier
       if test[i] in detM:
           CAT = "Det"
           Nb = "Sg"
           GND = "M"
           yield test[i],":","CAT:",CAT,",","Genre:",GND,",","Nombre:",Nb

       #Nom Masculin Singulier
       elif test[i] in nomM:
           CAT = "N"
           Nb = "Sg"
           GND = "M"
           yield test[i],":","CAT:",CAT,",","Genre:",GND,",","Nombre:",Nb
```

You can iterate over this, or convert it straight into a list:

```
for val in get_pos_tag(string):
    print(val)

# or

print(list(get_pos_tag(string)))
```

Also the `return get_pos_tag(string)` at the end of the file (outside all other functions) doesn't actually do anything (and I'm not sure it's valid).'

---

Question Clarified Old Answer:

This is because you aren't returning anything from within `get_pos_tag()`, but just calling `print`. The `print()` function doesn't transfer any values, it simply displays them.

Wherever you have a `print()` function, replace it with a `return`.

Comment: That only makes me get the first item recognized `un : CAT: Det , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg` but `garçon : CAT: N , Genre: M , Nombre: Sg` is not there, and I need them both!

Comment: Oh, is the `if ... else` supposed to be in some loop? If so, could you update your question to include it?

Comment: Yes it is supposed, because am checking the same element ,

I updated it, done

Comment: Sorry, was unclear there, didn't mean update to include my result, I rolled back the edit for you. Could you add where the `i` variable comes from?

Comment: the i comes from the entry, it represents every element in it

Comment: Thank you, much clearer, I think I understand what you are saying now. I've updated my question. In the future, we're able to help you quicker if you can give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something that we can run super quickly ourselves that shows the rough behavior of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure I will :)

Answer (score 2):

The right data structure for your task is not a list of strings but a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
def get_pos_tag(s):

    def d(e):
        if e in ['un','le']:
            return {'CAT':'Det', 'Genre':'M', 'Nombre':'Sg'}
        if e in ['garçon','verre','chair']:
            return {'CAT':'N', 'Genre':'M', 'Nombre':'Sg'}

    return {entréé:d(entréé) for entréé in s.split()}
```

As an example of use:

```
d = get_pos_tag("un garçon")

for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])
```

yields

```
un {'CAT': 'Det', 'Genre': 'M', 'Nombre': 'Sg'}
garçon {'CAT': 'N', 'Genre': 'M', 'Nombre': 'Sg'}
```

and

```
print(d['un']['Genre'])
```

yields

```
M
```

---

ps — I substituted `nltk.word_tokenize` (that I've not installed) with `s.split` for the purpose of testing my solution.